# Setting up a toggle switch in PHP, Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, togglebutton

Right now I am running a PHP script.  I have a basic button encoded into it, I am needing to change from a basic button to a toggle button.  I have tried with Jquery but have been unsuccessful.  My basic code for the button is

```
<button onclick=\"update('homestead')\"  class=\"btn btn-default\"> Homestead </button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  And if I can clear up anything let me know, I am new to using this style of coding.  My background has been SQL Server.

Sorry for being unclear.  I have the file this button is on with a lot of other basic buttons, each one links to an update file that either adds or subtracts from a SQL table.  This is all controlled by a controller and displays everything on a monitor.  For this one button though I need to call a distinctive location that sets 1 specific attribute, when pressed.  When it hasn't been pressed, or has been pressed a second time I need it to remove the attribute, so be blank.

Comment: Your question is unclear, describe a bit about what you want to toggle (probably a div)!

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes I do have bootstrap files

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.fn.toggleable = function(){this.on("click",function(){$(this).toggleClass("toggle-toggle").trigger("toggle",{on: $(this).hasClass("toggle-toggle")});});return this;};


$(function(){
    
    $("#toggle_me").toggleable().on("toggle",function(event,toggle){
        if(toggle.on){
            $(this).html("Toggle Me: On");
        } else {
            $(this).html("Toggle Me: Off");
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="toggle_me">Toggle Me: Off</button>
```